# APT and the Devel Release

Tags: apt, ppa, development

So I was looking around on the web, and I found out about the development release. It really popped out to me, because it's a rolling release, based on what I understand. I am aware that it sacrifices stability and support. So I loaded a virtual machine with an Ubuntu Server net installer for Trusty Tahr, and install the XUbuntu Desktop. I then changed every reference from `trusty` to `devel` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and after tons and tons and tons of dependency problems and upgrading I had upgraded to "Ubuntu Xenial Xerius (Development Branch)", according to `lsb_release -a`. Now I have a few questions:

1. I added one of the PPA's from the host machine that only support precise, trusty, and vivid. (The [screenfetch](https://launchpad.net/~djcj/+archive/ubuntu/screenfetch) PPA). If you look on it's page, you can see there is only those three packages. So I tried adding the ppa, and changing every occurrence of `xenial` to `devel` in it's file located in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Tried installing it, and it worked! Does every PPA support this "devel" release?
2. As said in the first question, I had to replace all of the `xenial` occurrences with `devel`. How can I change the machine's codename to `devel` and make APT automatically add PPA's as "devel" release?

Comment: For this PPA, `devel` means `vivid`. http://ppa.launchpad.net/djcj/screenfetch/ubuntu/dists/devel/Release

Comment: Is there a guarantee that a `devel` version will always be available for a package?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "a devel version" and by "a package".

Comment: By "a package" I mean any package in a PPA. And by "a devel version" I mean packages that I can install for the codename "devel".

Comment: It doesn't look like a good idea to use the codename `devel` because for the PPA you mentioned, like I said it will give you a `vivid` package, which is really not what you want. My *guess* is that the `devel` section is automatically created when a PPA creates packages for the current development release *at the time the package is created*. If after that a new development release comes out but the PPA has no packages for the new one, `devel` will still point to the old one.

Comment: By the way, in this particular case the official Xenial repositories have the same version of `screenfetch` (version `3.7.0-1`) as the PPA, so there is no reason whatsoever to use the PPA anymore, and you should remove it.